# python web: Safari can't connect to the server

Tags: server, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I used vagrant ubuntu server(16.04): 127.0.0.1, and port is 2222 for developing web application, the test code (app.py)as following:

```
import logging; logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

import asyncio, os, json, time
from datetime import datetime

from aiohttp import web

def index(request):
    return web.Response(body=b'<h1>Awesome</h1>')

@asyncio.coroutine
def init(loop):
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/', index)
    srv = yield from loop.create_server(app.make_handler(), '127.0.0.1', 2222)
    logging.info('server started at http://127.0.0.1:9000...')
    return srv

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
loop.run_forever()
```

After I run the code in the ubuntu server as following:
[image: test app]

and then I want to test the app in browser,  but there is no response! and error:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the server is listening on IP 127.0.0.1 on the VM so you will not be able to access from your host.

If you want to access it from your host browser, you'd need to run your server on a dedicated IP or on the `0.0.0.0` IP so change to

```
srv = yield from loop.create_server(app.make_handler(), '127.0.0.1', 9000)
```

then make sure to forward this port from your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000
```

and you'll be able to access it on `http://localhost:9000` from your host

Answer (score 0):

the default `2222` port is from forwarded `22` from host machine ssh.. are you sure you `port_forwarded` setting in your `Vagrantfile` is correct..?also check in you host machine if the port that you want to open is really open using `sudo netstat -ntlp` usually vagrant port will have a PID of `VBOXHeadless`